# Is it true that $C\{n!\}=C\{n^n\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $M_0,M_1,\ldots$ are positive numbers. Let $C\{M_n\}$ be the class of all infinitely differentiable complex functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that if $f \in C\{M_n\}$, then there are positive constants $\beta_f$ and $B_f$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\|D^nf\|_\infty \le \beta_fB_f^nM_n
\end{equation*} for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$. Since $n! \le n^n$ for all positive integers $n$, the definition gives $C\{n!\} \subseteq C\{n^n\}$. My question is whether it is true that $C\{n^n\} \subseteq C\{n!\}$. So far I can't find a counter example.

Comment: @Ramanujan - these are quasi analytic functions and they generally are treated within complex analysis for historical reasons at least;to do this one uses Stirling approximation to show the reverse inclusion since $\beta_fB_f^nn^n \le \delta_f(2eB_f)^nn!$ for example, since $\frac{n^n}{(2e)^nn!} \to 0$ and we can adjust the constant in front for the finite number of values for which the ratio is greater than one

Comment: Thanks! So I can get the equality now.

Comment: Is there any good book for this topic: quasi analytic functions?

Comment: I would look up Denjoy Carleman theorem and see what references pop-up; Rudin RC has some stuff in chapter 19